# Partitioned Job can't stop by itself after finishing? Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, partition

I wrote a Job of two Steps, with one of two steps being a partitioning step.
The partition step uses TaskExecutorPartitionHandler and runs 5 slave steps in threads.
The job is started in the main() method. But it's not stopping after every slave ItemReader returned null- the finish symbol. And even after the program ran past the last line of code in main() method (which is System.out.println("Finished")) the program process won't stop, hanging in memory and doing nothing. I have to press the stop button on Eclipse's panel to stop the program.

the following is the content of a JobExecution returned by JobLauncher.run(), signaling the successful status of the Job run..

> JobExecution: id=0, version=2, startTime=Fri Nov 27 06:05:23 CST 2015, endTime=Fri Nov 27 06:05:39 CST 2015, lastUpdated=Fri Nov 27 06:05:39 CST 2015, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=0, version=0, Job=[jobCensoredPages]], jobParameters=[{}]
>
> 7217
> Finished

Why does a Spring Batch program with a successful Job run still hang?
Please point me where to work it out. I'm suspecting the multithreading part managed by Spring Batch does not stop..

simple job run code

```
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("jobPages");
        try {
            JobParameters p=new JobParametersBuilder()
                .toJobParameters();
            
            JobExecution result = launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());
         
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        context.getBean("idSet");
        AtomicInteger n=(AtomicInteger) context.getBean("pageCount");
        System.out.println(n.get());        
        System.out.println("Finished");
```

Configuation for Patitioner and PatitionHandler

```
    @Bean @Autowired 
    public PartitionHandler beanPartitionHandler(
        TaskExecutor beanTaskExecutor, 
        @Qualifier("beanStepSlave") Step beanStepSlave
        ) throws Exception
    {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler h=new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        h.setGridSize(5);
        h.setTaskExecutor(beanTaskExecutor);
        h.setStep(beanStepSlave);   
        h.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        return h;
    }
    @Bean public TaskExecutor beanTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor e = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        e.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        e.setCorePoolSize(5);
        e.afterPropertiesSet();
        return e;
    }
```

the only step and it's slave step

```
@Bean public Step beanStepMaster(
        Step beanStepSlave,
        Partitioner beanPartitioner,
        PartitionHandler beanPartitionHandler
        )   throws Exception 
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory().get("stepMaster")
        .partitioner(beanStepSlave)
        .partitioner("stepSlave", beanPartitioner)
        .partitionHandler(partitionHandler)
        .build();
    }
    @Bean @Autowired 
    public Step beanStepSlave(
        ItemReader<String> beanReaderTest,
        ItemProcessor<String, String> beanProcessorTest,
        ItemWriter<String> beanWriterTest) throws Exception{
        return stepBuilderFactory().get("stepSlave")
            .<String, String>chunk(1)
            .reader(beanReaderTest)
            .processor(beanProcessorTest)
            .writer(beanWriterTest)
            .build();
    }
```

My pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow. First thing you should probably read the guide to asking questions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some help. Your question will get more help if you include code (using the code formatting option in the editor) with comments at the point where you are getting the error. People will more easily be able to understand your problem and help.

Comment: I just hope those who know Spring Batch's internals well or who had the same problem fixed can shine some light on my problem. I can provide whatever you need to make an analysis..

Comment: It's Spring Batch framework related.

Comment: SpringBatch doesn't hang, it finished. But for some reason, the spring context is not closed. Are you using SpringBoot? And/or do you have any other spring modules active, like the webmodule? Or an actuator? It would help to know which dependencies are inside your pom; could you please post them. Also, a threaddump after you received the "Finished" message could provide meaningful insights.

Comment: +Hansjoerg Wingeier thank you for the very helpful insight. I'm not using SpringBoot, just SpringBatch in a helloworld commandline program.I've put "RELEASE" to the version tag in my pom.ini, so the version of Spring Framework and SpringBatch should be the latest. Currently I'm suspecting the hanging was caused by misused Partitioner or PartitionHandler or TaskExecutor. they are so confusing as there are so few examples about how to use them. I dont know how exectly Partition step handles threads so threaddump seem unlikely for this.But in log files, only one of 5 designed threads seem working

Answer (score 10):

I also had difficulty with my partitioned Spring batch application hanging on completion when I used a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.  In addition, I saw that the executor was not allowing the work of all the partitions to finish.

I found two ways of solving those issues.

The first solution is using a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. If you do not mind the extra overhead in re-creating threads, this is a simple fix.

The second solution is creating a JobExecutionListener that calls shutdown on the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

I created a JobExecutionListener like this:

```
@Bean
public JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor) {
    return new JobExecutionListener() {
        private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = executor;
        @Override
        public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            taskExecutor.shutdown();
        }
    };
}
```

and added it to my Job definition like this:

```
@Bean
public Job partitionedJob(){
    return jobBuilders.get("partitionedJob")
            .listener(jobExecutionListener(taskExecutor()))
            .start(partitionedStep())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The `System.exit()` solution works, but seems hack-y. This is a much better answer.

Comment: Simple is always sweet.! Awesome answer.

Answer (score 8):

All of the above answers are hack/work around.
Root cause of the issue posted in the question is that the threadPoolTaskExecutor doesn't shares the lifecycle of the step. Hence while destroying the step/job context , the threadpool is not destroyed automatically and it is running forever. 
Bringing the threadPoolExecutor within the the stepContext "@StepScope" should do the trick. Spring takes care of destroying it.

`@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {`

Comment: This is the proper answer I believe and it works for me. Adding additional info to this answer, The bean scope of the task executor might not always be `step` depending on where it's used, at job scope or step scope. For example when it's used to process flows in split flow, you'll want it to be `@JobScope` or else you'll have `ScopeNotActiveException` exception saying "Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread". Another example is when it's used as the step executor, you'll need `@StepScope` or else you'll have similar exception.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions to your problem, although I don't know the cause.

First, you can use a `CommandLineJobRunner` to launch the `Job`. See documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html). This class automatically exits the program at the end of the job and converts the ExitStatus to a return code (`COMPLETED` = 0, `FAILED` = 1...). The default return code are provided by a `SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper`.

The second solution would be to manually call a `System.exit()` instruction after your `JobLauncher.run()`. You can also convert the `ExitStatus` of the `Job` manually and use it in your manual exit :

```
// Create Job
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);

// Create return codes mapper
SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper mapper = new SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper();

// Start Job
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

// Close context
context.close();

// Map codes and exit
String status = execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode();
Integer returnCode = mapper.intValue(status);
System.exit(returnCode);
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. adding System.exit() does exit the program in the end. that tells me the problem is likely in the partition step. I dont know what exactly cause SpringBatch to hang... I wish there are more in documentation about Partition Step's behaviors with examples, especially on how to do threading with Paritioner, paritionHandler,TaskExecutor. I only found one online and another in the book Pro SpringBatch.. Thank you.. your code help to mend the problem.

Comment: // Create return codes mapper
        SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper mapper = new SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper();
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            LOGGER.info("Job finished.");
        } else if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {
            LOGGER.error("******Job failed...");
        }
        String status = jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode();
        Integer returnCode = mapper.intValue(status);
        System.exit(returnCode);