# Spring batch ThreadPoolTaskExecutor hook and JVM destroy process don't finish

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My Spring Batch example read from file and write to h2 in memory db.

When the flow don't throw exception, all goes well.

If an SQL Exception is thrown, 2 thread of task executor remain in running mode, and DestroJavaVM not complete, remaining in Running mode.

My job:

```
    @Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(masterStep()).end().build();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("masterStep")
public Step masterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("masterStep")
            .partitioner("step1", partitioner)
            .step(step1())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Person, Person>chunk(10)
            .reader(personItemReader)
            .processor(new PersonItemProcessor())
            .writer(writer)
            .listener(writerListener)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(DuplicateKeyException.class)
            .skipLimit(10)
            .build();
}
```

What may be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to shutdown the task executor after the job has finished? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39692342/5019386

Comment: With task executor shutdown the batch terminate. I don't undestand why it will be necessary. Without the shutdown, if no exception is thrown, the batch terminate correctly.

Comment: Is this a web application or one-time run job form the command line?
If run-once then you should probably make your thread pool to create so called daemon threads which do not prevent JVM from exit when all other threads have done their job. `pool.setDaemon(true)`